# docker push to nexus 3 - invalid checksum digest format

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nexus, nexus3

Though I am able to successfully push a newly pulled docker image to Nexus 3 docker hosted repo, an error like **"invalid checksum digest format"** is thrown at the end. I pulled "jenkins:latest" from dockerhub, then tagged it and then pushed it to a nexus docker hosted repo.

```
f3e4e0468545: Pushed
656120ad8c56: Pushed
30f9a83f20f3: Pushed
78dbfa5b7cbc: Pushed
invalid checksum digest format
```

I know Nexus 3 is not LTS yet, but want to be sure that its not my environment settings. I have an insecure docker registry on 18443

`docker info
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 53
Server Version: 1.10.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 89
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-53-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 3.86 GiB`

```
Client:
 Version:      1.10.1
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   9e83765
 Built:        Thu Feb 11 19:27:08 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.1
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   9e83765
 Built:        Thu Feb 11 19:27:08 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Answer (score 7):

Docker version 1.10 was not out when Nexus 3.0m7 was released.  We are working on adding support for it now.  This specific issue is being tracked here:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9766

UPDATE: This issue/ticket is resolved now in Nexus Repository Manager 3.0.0-03.  For upgrade instructions see https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/217967608-How-to-Upgrade-Nexus-3-Milestone-m7-to-3-0-0-Final.